# using flann with a memory mapped index

Tags: c++, mmap

I use flann with a large index that uses a lot of RAM.

I want to be able to share the flann index between several processes.

Is is feasible to make flann use a memory mapped file for its index, so it can be shared between several processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a partial solution:

The high memory use includes the flann tree, which is managed by flann. 
The tree doesn't include the actual data - only indexes to an external matrix.
this matrix can be easily memory mapped (I used boost)

In my scenario this saved about 70% of the RAM.